# Savoir vs. connaître en logique

Tags: traduction, usage, verbes, constructions

La question est motivée par [celle-ci dans la communauté de philosophie](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/q/94553/61899). À citer:

> I've been researching Allan Hazlitt's claim that knowledge attribution isn't factive, i.e. the claim that (in ordinary language) sentences of the form "A knows p" can be true even if the proposition p is false (see "The Myth of Factive Verbs" and "Factive presupposition and the truth condition on knowledge").

> People (ordinary English speakers, not philosophers) do speak that way sometimes, or show patterns of judgement that are aligned with a non-factive interpretation for the word "know". The most prominent counter-argument that I'm aware of says that when people speak that way or make those judgements, it's based on a non-literal interpretation of "know". In particular, the claim is that it involves "protagonist projection" (see e.g. Richard Holton's "Some Telling Examples: A Reply to Tsohatzidis"), where someone adopts the perspective of the protagonist. If this is the case, then when someone says "A knows p" in a situation where p has been established as false, then what they literally mean is that "A thinks they know p".

Je me demande, si cette ambiguité est exclue en français, à force de differencier entre *savoir* et *connaître*. Ainsi, si on prend une proposition fausse, comme

> *Trump a gagné l'election présidentielle 2020*

alors

> *Alice sait que Trump a gagné l'election présidentielle 2020.*

est faux (parce qu'il n'a pas gagné), mais

> *Alice connaît que Trump a gagné l'election présidentielle 2020.*

peut être vrai, si Alice croît la théorie de complot, que l'élection a été volée à Trump.

---

Lecture supplementaire:

- [Factive verbs](https://file:///home/puller/T%C3%A9l%C3%A9chargements/Factive%20and%20non-factive%20verbs%202016_17.pdf)
- [Allan Hazlett, *The Myth of Factive Verbs*](https://aristotle.rutgers.edu/joomlatools-files/docman-files/Hazlett.pdf)

Comment: Plus que la distinction entre "savoir" et "connaître", c'est plutôt celle entre "savoir" et "croire" (ou "penser") que vous cherchez à comprendre. On ne peut pas utiliser "connaître" dans la phrase que vous citez en exemple.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I've been researching Allan Hazlitt's claim that knowledge attribution isn't factive, i.e. the claim that (in ordinary language) sentences of the form "A knows p" can be true even if the proposition p is false.

1. Alice ne peut pas dire *je connais p*, c'est-à-dire *je connais que Trump a gagné*, cette construction est grammaticalement incorrecte, on dit *je sais que p*.

- Alice dit donc *je sais que p*, c'est-à-dire *je suis au courant que p* ou *je suis convaincue que p*. On lui a dit: p est une certitude, alors qu'il s'agit d'une simple allégation sans éléments probants.

2. Alice partage cette allégation, devenue pour elle une certitude, avec une tierce personne. Que peut-elle en penser? Qu'*Alice croit que p*. C'est un fait, Alice est convaincue.

- Cependant il lui faut remettre la conviction d'Alice dans son contexte: Alice croit que p *mais* n'a pas d'éléments probants. Ce devrait être sa propre conclusion d'après sa conversation avec Alice.
- En revanche il n'est pas légitime pour lui de dire: *Alice sait que p*, parce qu'on acquiert pas le *savoir* en prêtant foi à des rumeurs, mais par des déductions rigoureuses.

3. Le dernier point est le point-clé, il confirme qu'en français aussi on est concerné par le contre-argument évoqué:

> The most prominent counter-argument that I'm aware of says that  [...] it's based on a non-literal interpretation of "know". [...] when someone says "A knows p" in a situation where p has been established as false, then what they literally mean is that "A thinks they know p".

4. 

> Je me demande, si cette ambiguité est exclue en français, à force de differencier entre savoir et connaître.

- Cette ambiguïté existe donc en français, non pas entre *savoir* et *connaître*, mais entre *savoir* et *croire*, c'est l'opposition croyance-savoir, dogme-raisonnement rigoureux. Lorsqu'Alice dit *je sais que...*, cela n'implique pas qu'elle sache réellement. Avant d'avoir confirmation de la réalité des faits, tout ce qu'on peut dire c'est qu'*elle croit savoir*.

La plupart d'entre-nous font bien la différence, mais il y a les autres, dont le nombre semble ne pas devoir cesser de croître. L'[agnotologie](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Agnotologie) ([page en anglais](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Agnotology), bien plus fournie), la science qui traite de la désinformation, s'intéresse à ce qui amène Alice à croire sans chercher à savoir. Et elle apporte des réponses, en particulier l’inconfort de la [dissonance cognitive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cognitive_dissonance).